# How to read, reorganize, and plot flexibly for temporal and spatial queries on a large multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a csv file with the following structure, representing values `(A, B, C)` in space `(s)` and time `(t)`. The goal is to right a (preferebly intractive) python CLI that can take
various spatial `(s)` and temporal `(t)` queries and generate summary csv and graphs (`val`s are different).

```
t=1
s,A,B,C
s_0_0, val, val, val, val
s_0_1, val, val, val, val
s_0_2, val, val, val, val
s_1_0, val, val, val, val
s_1_1, val, val, val, val
s_1_2, val, val, val, val
s_2_0, val, val, val, val
s_2_1, val, val, val, val
s_2_2, val, val, val, val
s_3_0, val, val, val, val
s_3_1, val, val, val, val
s_3_2, val, val, val, val
t=2
A,B,C,D
s,A,B,C
s_0_0, val, val, val, val
s_0_1, val, val, val, val
s_0_2, val, val, val, val
s_1_0, val, val, val, val
s_1_1, val, val, val, val
s_1_2, val, val, val, val
s_2_0, val, val, val, val
s_2_1, val, val, val, val
s_2_2, val, val, val, val
s_3_0, val, val, val, val
s_3_1, val, val, val, val
s_3_2, val, val, val, val
...
t=1,000,000
A,B,C,D
s,A,B,C
s_0_0, val, val, val, val
s_0_1, val, val, val, val
s_0_2, val, val, val, val
s_1_0, val, val, val, val
s_1_1, val, val, val, val
s_1_2, val, val, val, val
s_2_0, val, val, val, val
s_2_1, val, val, val, val
s_2_2, val, val, val, val
s_3_0, val, val, val, val
s_3_1, val, val, val, val
s_3_2, val, val, val, val
```

I'm designing something like this `(c, r, t) = given input (#cols, #rows, #times)` with (oc, or, ot) = desired output (#sub_cols, #sub_rows, #starttime, #endtime, #step):

`cli -f in.csv -c 4 -r 3 -t 1000000 -f out.csv -oc 2 -or 2 -ot 300 500 200`

To illustrate the problem better, I'm doing bunch of operation (incl. `chunk`, `concat`, `pivot`) on this:

[image]

to get something like this (**which probably can be restructured better**):

[image]

So ultimately can produce bunch of summary plots such as:

(1) Temporal: lineplot `A vs t`, `B vs t` and `C vs t` per each `s`

(2) Spatial: heatmap for avg and peak value of `(A, B, C)` for sliced data

Here is my code. I'm wondering how to read, reorganzie and write **flexible plotting** to handle various queries for both temporal and spatial cases:

```
 __name__ == '__main__':
    args = arg_parser()
    file = args.filename
    nblocks = args.rows * args.cols #3 * 4
    nsteps = args.steps #1000000

    # assume input and output cols, rows and timesteps are given

    nheaders = 2  # for recurring headers t=time and s,A,B,C
    nrows = nsteps * (nblocks + nheaders)
    print(nrows)
    chunksize = nblocks
    skiprows1 = np.arange(0, nrows, nblocks + nheaders) #intervals
    skiprows2 = np.arange(31, nrows, nblocks + nheaders) #intervals
    skiprows = np.insert(skiprows2, np.arange(len(skiprows1)), skiprows1)
    reader = pd.read_csv(file, iterator=True, chunksize=chunksize, header=0, skiprows=skiprows)
    chunk_dic_indexed = {k: chunk.set_index(['s']) for k, chunk in enumerate(reader)}
    dfr = pd.concat(chunk_dic_indexed, axis=0, ignore_index=False)
    dfr.index.set_names('t', level=0, inplace=True)
    dfr_p = dfr.reset_index().pivot('t', 's', ' A')
    
    f, a = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    dfr_p.loc[:, ['s_1_0','s_1_1', 's_2_0', 's_2_1']].plot(kind='bar')
    f, a = plt.subplots(4, 1)
    dfr_p.loc[:, 's_1_0'].plot(kind='bar', ax=a[0])
    dfr_p.loc[:, 's_1_1'].plot(kind='bar', ax=a[1])
    dfr_p.loc[:, 's_2_0'].plot(kind='bar', ax=a[2])
    dfr_p.loc[:, 's_2_1'].plot(kind='bar', ax=a[3])


    plt.show()
    del dfr, dfr_p
    exit()
```